# Running RobotFramework Tests on Sauce Labs - error with timing out

Tags: selenium, robotframework, saucelabs

I have existing selenium tests written in Robot IDE Framework that I'm trying to run in Sauce Labs.

I'm using the sample test from this tutorial to see if I can get at least one test running. http://datakurre.pandala.org/2014/03/cross-browser-selenium-testing-with.html

The test passes locally, and passes all the tests on Sauce Labs, but then times out and gives and error, "Test did not see a new command for 90 seconds. Timing out.
error" because it's not disconnecting Remote Web Driver.

I've tried all of these, together and separately at the end of the "Close test browser" function:

- Close all browsers
- Process close
- Stop selenium server

I've also tried adding ((RemoteWebDriver) getCurrentWebDriver()).quit() in one of the python functions that runs during the closing process. I'm new to Selenium and Robot Framework, so I'm not sure how to grab the Remote Web Driver.

Here is the code, in case that helps:

```
    *** Settings ***
Test Setup        Open test browser
Test Teardown     Close test browser
Resource          ../../Keywords/super.txt
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           ../../Library/SauceLabs.py

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN_FAIL_MSG}    Incorrect username or password.
${COMMAND_EXECUTOR}    http://username:key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
${REMOTE_URL}     http://username:key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}    username:name,access-key:key,name:Testing RobotFramework,platform:Windows 8.1,version:26,browserName:CHROME,javascriptEnabled:True

*** Test Cases ***
Incorrect username or password
    [Tags]    Login
    Go to    https://saucelabs.com/login
    Page should contain element    id=username
    Page should contain element    id=password
    Input text    id=username    anonymous
    Input text    id=password    secret
    Click button    id=submit
    Page should contain    ${LOGIN_FAIL_MSG}
    [Teardown]

*** Keywords ***
Open test browser
    Open browser    http://www.google.com    ${BROWSER}    \    remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}    desired_capabilities=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}

Close test browser
    Run keyword if    '${REMOTE_URL}' != ''    Report Sauce status    ${SUITE_NAME} | ${TEST_NAME}    ${TEST_STATUS}    ${TEST_TAGS}    ${REMOTE_URL}
    Close all browsers
    Process close
    Stop selenium server
```

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to with `${DESURED_CAPABILITIES}`? What keyword is timing out?

Comment: None of the keywords are timing out. It just never stops running, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to stop RemoteWebDriver. Keep in mind that we're using Robot IDE, which is the GUI interface, so I can't just add driver.quit(), because the driver gets started by Open browser    http://www.google.com    ${BROWSER}    \    remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}    desired_capabilities=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}

Comment: The first step will be to stop using the IDE and try running the command from a command prompt. That will eliminate one thing that could be going wrong, and it's possible you'll see an error message in the display.

Comment: I'm able to see the selenium log already in Sauce Labs. There are no errors on keywords. I just need to figure out how to access the Remote Web Driver.

Comment: you shouldn't need to access the remote web driver. I've written tests that run on sauce and everything worked as expected. There must be something else causing the problem. Have you tried running from the command line? Maybe RIDE is the culprit.

Comment: I need to access the Remote Web Driver to end the connection with Sauce Labs. (That's what is suggested by Sauce Labs.) From their tech support: "I believe the problem here lies with we aren't ending the RemoteWebDriver session correctly. Sauce Labs relies on a call from the RemoteWebDriver to end tests.

In Python this would look like:

self.driver.quit()

Do you know what Robot framework is transcribing those commands into?"

Comment: I don't think you should have to do that. Maybe I'm wrong, but at least for me, a call to "Close all browsers" was all I needed to disconnect from saucelabs. If you look in the code for Selenium2Library, it does call `driver.quit()` from "Close All Browsers".

Comment: You can also try adding `--loglevel DEBUG` to see if you get more useful information. Again, do this from the command line rather than RIDE to eliminate RIDE as part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special to close down the connection. My guess is, there's something in your test that is preventing the browser from being closed. My recommendation is to start with a simpler example, and start from the command line. Get that working, and then work your way up to being able to run something more complex from within RIDE.

Here is a working example where I removed all of the extra stuff in the test. I am able to run this both from the command line and via RIDE on Windows. You'll have to add in your own key, however:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
| @{_tmp} 
| ... | name:Testing RobotFramework Selenium2Library,
| ... | browserName:internet explorer,
| ... | platform:Windows 8,
| ... | version:10

| ${CAPABILITIES}   | ${EMPTY.join(${_tmp})} 
| ${KEY}            | <put your username:key here>
| ${REMOTE_URL}     | http://${KEY}@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
| ${URL}            | https://saucelabs.com/login
| ${LOGIN_FAIL_MSG} | Incorrect username or password.

*** Test cases ***
| Example of connecting to saucelabs via robot
| | [Setup] 
| | ... | Open Browser
| | ... | ${URL}
| | ... | remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}
| | ... | desired_capabilities=${CAPABILITIES}
| | 
| | Page should contain element | id=username
| | Page should contain element | id=password
| | 
| | Input text | id=username | anonymous
| | Input text | id=password | secret
| | Click button | id=submit
| | 
| | Page should contain | ${LOGIN_FAIL_MSG}
| | 
| | [Teardown] | Close all browsers
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran your code in the command line and it worked, then refactored it to run in RIDE. I wasn't able to get the Open Browser command to run without specifying the browser, though.

Comment: In your code, you didn't specify the broswer in the Open Browser command. I'm not able to get mine to do that, even from the command line. Not sure if I should open a new question for this.

Comment: @Ana: I don't understand your comment. A week ago you write that you ran it from the command line and it worked. Now you're saying it _didn't_ run on the command line? I'm confused. As to specifying the browser -- because the test talks to a remote system, the browser is defined in the `${CAPABILITIES}` variable.

Comment: I was only able to get it to work by adding the browser name (see my comment on Sept.16). The Selenium2Library says the browser name is required. I'm not sure how to get the commands to run only remotely. http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Open Browser

Comment: @Ana: the browser isn't required since it has a default value of firefox. It would only be required if there were no default.